# Uploading Extension in Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, upload, marketplace

I'm uploading extension in magento marketplace but while uploading extension file which in is TGZ format i'm getting error "The "package.xml" file does not exist; please verify the archive."

[image: **enter image description here**]

Folder Structure

App->code->local->AffilNow->Module->etc,helper,Model
     etc->Modules->afillnow.xml

Comment: attach your folder structure

Comment: App->code->local->AffilNow->Module->etc,helper,Model
     etc->Modules->afillnow.xml

Comment: Hi, is your extension is live as i am facing the same issue, icreated the package.xml but not able to validate it before submitting for approval

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217669/how-to-use-create-extension-package-in-magento-1-9

Answer (score 5):

You are facing the error because your package file is missing **package.xml** file.
**package.xml** is automatically created when you package a Magento 1 extension from

> System > Magento Connect > Package Extension

The file will contain details about the extension like,

- name
- version
- channel
- license
- description
- author
- dependencies,
  etc..
  It will also contain details for your modules content/files and folders structure, which will be used when you install a package from your admin panel

  > System > Magento Connect Manager

So this file is essential for your Magento 1 packages.
How to Create **package.xml**

1. Extract your current package in a Magento 1 setup and install
   it.
2. Now to to Admin Panel > System > Package Extension
3. Add all details about your extension
4. Click "Save Data and Create Package" button
5. Package file will be in `var/connect/` folder

   [Reference](https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-create-an-extension-package-file-in-magento/)

Comment: can u see my question on same topic https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217669/how-to-use-create-extension-package-in-magento-1-9